# Given sets G and B, find intersection and find the union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The sets G and B are given below.

$G=\{a,e,k\}$
$B=\{d,f,h\}$

Find the intersection of G and B.
Find the union of G and B.

Comment: what are g, e and b exactly? do you mean the elements of the sets or the sets themselves?

Answer (score 5):

$$G=\{a,e,k\},\quad  B=\{d,f,h\}$$

The intersection of sets $G$ and $B$ is denoted by $G\cap B$ and contains all elements that are in $G$ **and** also in $B$. In this case, there are **no elements in common**, hence the intersection is empty:

$$G\cap B = \{x\mid x\in G \;\text{and}\;x \in B\} = \varnothing$$

The union of sets $G$ and $B$ is denoted $G\cup B$ and contains all elements that are in either $G$ **or** in $B$:

$$G\cup B = \{x\mid x\in G \;\text{or}\; x \in B\} = \{a, e, k, d, f, h\}$$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to share his or her reason(s) for downvoting a perfectly correct post?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but its worth pointing out that we don't know for certain whether all those elements are distinct or not. Of course, they probably are.

Comment: I did the downvote by mistake which I just fixed. I don't like the idea to answer a question when another one has already answered it, but it's not a reason to downvote, off course

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $G$ and $B$ are sets, and the rest are their elements:

The intersection is the empty set, because no element is both in $G$ and $B$

The union is $a,e,k,d,f,h$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to share his or her reason(s) for downvoting a perfectly correct post?

Comment: Someone's going through and downvoting everyone. Probably, they think such questions should be closed and ignored rather than answered.

Comment: Well, I disagree. Even ones who new in here and doesn't quite know the rules, but request help, should recieve it!

Comment: Yes I agree with you.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the added "formatting", just to "pretty things up" :-)

Comment: Thanks @amWhy. It seems though that there's no sign from the asker :) ...

Comment: That happens, sometimes. *Big sigh*!

Comment: I didn't downvote.  The union is a set and when sets are expressed as a list of elements, we usually put curly braces around it.  That is, the union is $\{a,e,k,d,f,h\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what $a,d,e,f,k,h$ are. If some of them are equal to each other, then the intersection may be non-empty.